# How to Change http into https in Amazon Ec2 through LetsEncrypt

Tags: ssl, amazon-ec2, superuser

I have an ec2 instance in amazon ec2. In that i have  php files and mysql database.  I am connecting my database using ec2 by following

http://18.37.220.172/phpInsert.php. But i feel insecure. So i want to change into secure site.

Like this https://18.37.220.172/phpInsert.php

I have installed  letsencrypt ssl certificate in ec2 instance. but http is not changed into https.

How can i enable ssl in ec2 instance. i dont have any domain name.

so i want to convert my ip address https://18.37.220.172. Is it possible.

What i have to do ?

Answer (score 1):

letsencrypt does not support generating certificates without a domain name: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/certificate-for-public-ip-without-domain-name/6082

> It is possible to purchase certificates for IP addresses, but not from Let’s Encrypt. Let’s Encrypt may offer IP address certificates in the future, but as of September 2018 we do not.

Comment: ok. thanks for ur reply.l have domain name. and i  have linked my site into cloudflare(namespace).Suppose if i add the  domain name in letsencrypt. Where i can  add the namespace. is there any clear documentation for letsencrypt.

Comment: i'm not a cloudflare expert sorry, i suggest you to check out https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/ to understand the ways letsencrypt offer to verify you own the domain, and also this plugin that is specific for cloudflare https://certbot-dns-cloudflare.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: @CloudFire the domain name needs to be one that **you own.**